# "Ни при чём" или "ни причём"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Никак не могу сообразить, как правильно пишутся эти слова:
***ни при чём*** или ***ни причём***?

Бывает такое, когда вдруг "заклинит" на чём-то простом.

Comment: Предлагаю следующую трактовку этой фразы, дающую полное ее осмысление. Кроме "причем" и "при чем" эта НИ тут тоже совершенно не очевидна, всегда подмывает сказать и написать НЕ. Здесь просто не хватает АРТИКЛЯ, который обязателен в английском, итальянском и других родственных языках, а у нас стал факультативным. Вот как эта фраза должна звучать "правильно": нИ при ОДНОМ (a/any, un...) чем (-то). Сравните: non è UN problema (буквально: нет НИ ОДНОЙ проблемы). Никакого когнитивного диссонанса в восприятии, все очевидно и логично. (У итальянцев тоже есть сходная "засада". Та же по смыслу фраза мо

Answer (score 11):

В обычном контексте, т. е. в значении "не имеет отношения" - *ни при чем*, как и фиксируют словари.
Теоретически допускаю возможность написания *не причем* если речь идет о прямом отрицании союза "причем", правда контекст для этого должен быть весьма фантастическим.
Очень подробно несколько раз обсуждалось на Грамоте.

Вот начало, дальше уже лениво искать.
http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=1&i=43061&t=42957

Comment: Жаль, что лениво. Ссылка уже нерабочая.

Comment: @lorond *Жаль, что лениво. Ссылка уже нерабочая* - да, жаль. "Грамота" убила тот форум. Но тому не моя ленивость виной. Остальніе сслки, кабы даже я их и нашел, постигла бы та же участь. Там весь форум убит.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что ссылки умирают. Здорово, когда не просто ссылки указываются, а материал из ссылок переносится. На СО даже правило есть такое. Ну, в данном случае хотя бы кратко материал подан. Но интрига про фантастический контекст так и останется теперь нераскрытой. Хотя в ответах и обсуждениях ниже все же приоткрывается немного. :)

Answer (score 4):

Приходится следовать словарям и писать "ни при чем", "при чем" раздельно. (Если это не союз).  Хотя я не понимаю, почему орфографический словарь так активно вмешался и в морфологию. В "долопатинских" словарях мы находим, что слово "причем" в выражениях типа "Причём тут я?" является наречием, и тогда по правилу "нипричём" должно писаться слитно. Как и "где - нигде", "зачем - незачем".

Answer (score 2):

Не надо в этом случае ломать себе голову — лучше просто запомнить фразы: При чем здесь я? - Ты здесь ни при чем! 
Полностью согласна с вашими уточнениями, София. Что касается моего ответа, то он скорее является советом, как избежать ошибки при написании этой группы слов. Только в приведенном мною примере мы видим раздельное написание "ни при чем". Во всех остальных случаях, будь то в значении союза или наречия, написание - слитное.

У вас прекрасное "ощущение" языка, София! Дело в том, что ваше мнение относительно разумности существования формы "причём" только в роли союза, исключая его применение как наречия, полностью совпадает с утверждением  Ожегова, автора толкового словаря. Эта книга стала настольной, самой ценной книгой в моей библиотеке, где я нахожу практически все ответы на возникающие у меня вопросы. Так вот Ожегов утверждает: *причём, союз. К тому же, в добавление к этому. Не прав, причём ещё и спорит.* Никакой другой функции (по Ожегову + ваше "пожелание" и, конечно же, моё) кроме присоединительного союза, у этого слова нет и быть не может. Так что всё становится на свои места: если это не союз - значит, это предложная конструкция. И так как в предложении "Дети здесь при чём?" речь не идет о присоединительном союзе, мы имеем предложную конструкцию.
С уважением, Тами

P.S. Как я ни старалась, но не смогла придумать никаких предложений с "причём" в роли наречия. Если бы у этого слова была реально такая функция, то можно было бы подобрать  к нему наречие-синоним, что в данном случае оказывается невозможным.

Comment: Поломать голову (подумать) никогда не вредно. Задачу надо решить, а решение можно запомнить или можно при необходимости решить задачу еще раз. Иначе и сами можете забыть, и другим ничего не докажете. Слово ПРИЧЕМ имеет три значения: а) наречие ПРИЧЕМ (=с какой стати, зачем); б) союз ПРИЧЕМ (= союзу ПРИТОМ); В) предлог+местоимение ПРИ ЧЕМ (в какой связи). Вот примеры: а)  Дети-то здесь причем (= с какой стати)? Причем (= с какой стати)тут всё это; б) Неправ, причем (= притом) еще спорит. в) При чем тут я?

Comment: Что-то мне перестало "нравиться" наречие ПРИЧЕМ, так как различить по смыслу выражения "дети-то здесь причем?" и "при чем тут я?" очень сложно. Было бы разумным оставить две формы: союз ПРИЧЕМ и предложную форму ПРИ ЧЕМ, НИ ПРИ ЧЕМ.

Answer (score 1):

"Причем" - это присоединительный союз, который пишется слитно: Я люблю читать, причем много и с интересом. "При чем" - это местоимение с предлогом ("чём" можно заменить на "том": при том), поэтому верно писать  "ни при чем"

Answer (score 0):

"А при чём здесь я?Можно сказать при чём именно? при каком чём?-мест что в п.п.
-Ни при чём" Раньше были разночтения, сейчас словарь закрепил раздельное написание.

Он ушёл, причём очень быстро.Причём=И - союз, слитно.

http://gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords/25_266

Answer (score 0):

В качестве дополнения к ответу
Интересно, что проблемы с написанием этого выражения возникают также при выборе частиц НЕ/НИ. Здесь возможны два смысловых варианта:

(1) Он тут ни при чем - (не имеет отношения к делу), частица НИ одновременно является отрицательной и усилительной.

(2) Он остался не при чем -  остался с пустыми руками, это отрицательная частица НЕ, и этот вариант отражен в словарях Даля и Ушакова.
Однако с такой трактовкой не все согласны.

Comment: Главное, что не согласен словарь РАН, закрепивший написание ни при чём.

Comment: К сожалению, стремление нивелировать смысловые различия свойственно современной академической науке, но вряд ли это следует считать прогрессивным явлением. Чем больше оттенков смысла мы можем выразить, тем богаче язык. А у нас получается, что чем проще писать, тем легче жить.

Comment: Мне кажется, частица "ни" пишется здесь потому, что в местоимениях и местоименных наречиях НИ или НЕ зависит от ударения. Здесь безударное положение, поэтому "ни при чем"

Comment: Ударение - это формальный признак, но нужно и смысловое соответствие, то есть НИ - это усиление или отрицание+ усиление. Если мы скажем "он остался ни при чем", то это значит, что у него вообще ничего не осталось.

Comment: Еще немного об ударении как о ФОРМАЛЬНОМ ПРИЗНАКЕ. Например: "я ни с кем не советовался - не с кем советоваться". В первом случае частица НИ усиливает отрицание, выраженное частицей НЕ, а во втором случае используется отрицательная частица НЕ. Но мы такой анализ не проводим,так как есть формальный (сопутствующий) признак: частица НЕ - ударная,а частица НИ - безударная. Но вот для слов "мало, много" этот признак уже не действует, и приходится выбор делать по смыслу:    Упущенных побед немало, одержанных побед немного.И буду глух к моленьям и слезам, они нимало не помогут вам.